How to add Google Maps API to Flutter Web
I am reading Chapter 11 of the Flutter Cookbook - Second Edition by Simone Alessandria. I follow the following steps:

Create a new Flutter app, and call it map_recipe.

flutter pub add google_maps_flutter

I obtained Google Maps API key from here.

Open the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file in your project.
Add the following line under the icon launcher icon, in the application node:
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">


Set the minSdkVersion in the android/app/build.gradle file:
android {
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 20
}
}


But how to do it for Web?
The full code can be found on the author's GitHub

The steps you have followed is for adding Google maps to the Android platform.
To add Google Maps to your flutter web project, you would need to use the google_maps_flutter_web package and it since it is endorsed by the google_maps_flutter package, you just need to add your API key to the head your web/index.html file.
Add this script to your head tag:
<head>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
</head>


For web, you should provide your google key in the web/index.html. It should be inside of the head tag.
Documentation -  https://developers.google.com/maps/flutter-package/config#web

Please do check out the google_maps_flutter documentation for web it's available there.
You'll need to modify the web/index.html file of your Flutter Web application to include the Google Maps JS SDK. Check this out: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web
You don't need to add this dependency to your pubspec.yaml but follow its documentation. It will help you out. Modify the tag of your web/index.html to load the Google Maps JavaScript API, like so:
 <head>

  <!-- // Other stuff -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
</head>

I hope this helps and whenever you try to implement anything. Everytime go through the documentations.
