Google Map API does not with Flutter
I am reading Chapter 11 of the Flutter Cookbook - Second Edition by Simone Alessandria. I follow the following steps:

Create a new Flutter app, and call it map_recipe.

flutter pub add google_maps_flutter

flutter pub add location

flutter pub add http

I obtained Google Maps API key from here.

In the Android manifest file, which you can find at android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, add the following node to the Manifest node (before the application node):


But how to do it for the Web?
The code below displays the Google Maps heading, but the map is missing.
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// API set up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78675785/how-to-add-google-maps-api-to-flutter-web
/*One of the platform-independent plugins currently available is the flutter_map 
  plugin, available at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map.*/
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Map Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyMap(),
    );
  }
}

class MyMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyMap({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyMap> createState() => _MyMapState();
}

class _MyMapState extends State<MyMap> {
  late LatLng userPosition;
  List<Marker> markers = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Maps'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.map),
              onPressed: () => findPlaces(),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: findUserLocation(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition:
                      CameraPosition(target: snapshot.data, zoom: 12),
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers),
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            }));
  }

  Future<LatLng> findUserLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();
    LocationData userLocation;
    PermissionStatus hasPermission = await location.hasPermission();
    bool active = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (hasPermission == PermissionStatus.granted && active) {
      userLocation = await location.getLocation();
      userPosition = LatLng(userLocation.latitude!, userLocation.longitude!);
    } else {
      userPosition = const LatLng(51.5285582, -0.24167);
    }
    return userPosition;
  }

  Future findPlaces() async {
    const key = 'wxrhaENo';
    const placesUrl =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?';
    String url = placesUrl +
        'key=$key&type=restaurant&location=${userPosition.latitude},${userPosition.longitude}' +
        '&radius=1000';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      showMarkers(data);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Unable to retrieve places');
    }
  }

  showMarkers(data) {
    List places = data['results'];
    markers.clear();
    for (var place in places) {
      markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(place['reference']),
          position: LatLng(place['geometry']['location']['lat'],
              place['geometry']['location']['lng']),
          infoWindow:
              InfoWindow(title: place['name'], snippet: place['vicinity'])));
    }
    setState(() {
      markers = markers;
    });
  }
}

The full code can be found on the author's GitHub

Your question title does not explain the problem you're having. Google Map API does not with Flutter - does not WHAT with Flutter? And if the problem is with your code, why should we go and download the full code from the original author's GitHub? It's not the same as your code - you've apparently made changes to it.

Please do check out the google_maps_flutter documentation for web it's available there.
You'll need to modify the web/index.html file of your Flutter Web application to include the Google Maps JS SDK.
Check this out:
google_maps_flutter_web 
You don't need to add this dependency to your pubspec.yaml but follow its documentation. It will help you out.
Modify the  tag of your web/index.html to load the Google Maps JavaScript API, like so:
 <head>

  <!-- // Other stuff -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
</head>

I hope this helps and whenever you try to implement anything. Everytime go through the documentations.
